# Request: Excel equivalent of Google Spreadsheet ARRAYFORMULA + CONTINUE functionality

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Google Spreadsheets has a syntax permitting a user to specify an entire row, column, or area with a formula in a single cell.  For example, entering ...

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A3:A6))
```

... into cell C1 creates ...

```
   C
1  3
2  4
3  5
4  6
```

The contents of cells C2 through C4 are the formula "CONTINUE."

In Excel, entering {=ROW(A3:A6)} [CTRL] [SHIFT] [ENTER] creates ...

```
   C
1  3
2  
3  
4
```

Is there a way to get Excel to populate the remaining rows?

The desired end result is a formula which given ...

```
   A
1  Fred
2  Wilma
3  Barney
4  Betty
```

... will generate ...

```
   B
1  Fred Wilma
2  Barney Betty
3  
4
```

... without the user having to copy-paste.

Comment: Did you use shift-enter when entering the formula in excel?

Comment: @Lance Roberts, I used ctrl-shift-enter after entering the formula.  Does shift-enter do something different?

Comment: nah, I think I just forgot the ctrl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is exactly what you did, except before you enter the formula in excel, select the entire range, A1 through A4.  Then type the formula in and hit [ctrl][shift][enter].

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to replicate the Google Sheet ArrayFormula in MS Excel using the OFFSET() formula even if it's not as simple as the ArrayFormula function.

The full documention of the function can be found here.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-C8DE19AE-DD79-4B9B-A14E-B4D906D11B66

*A quick example*

**Google Sheet**

```
= ARRAYFORMULA(SQRT(Sheet2!A:A))
```

=> This will copy the full column A for the Sheet2 taking the square root of each value.

**Excel Version**

```
= SQRT(OFFSET(Sheet2!A1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet2!A:A),1))
```

=> This will take a reference of the column, but we have to manually specify the height and width of the reference before taking the square root of each value.